# include variables into pd.read_excel skiprows option

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This works perfectly.

```
for fname in glob.iglob(path):

    df2 = pd.read_excel(fname, skiprows=5, header=0).dropna(subset=['TreeNodeCode'],how='any')
```

However, each excel sheet has different numbers of rows to skip, so I am trying to make a variable to loop around skiprows:

I tried:

```
   skip_row_number=list('5')

   df2 = pd.read_excel(fname, skiprows=skip_row_number, header=0).dropna(subset=['Code'],how='any')
```

or

```
skip_row_number="5"

df2 = pd.read_excel(fname, skiprows=skip_row_number, header=0).dropna(subset=['Code'],how='any')
```

Both return:

line 3489, in dropna
    raise KeyError(list(np.compress(check, subset)))
KeyError: ['Code']

However, the user manual says

```
skiprows : list-like
Rows to skip at the beginning (0-indexed)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

so i am quite confused.  Could any guru enlighten?

We are in python 3.6 and pandas 0.21.0

Comment: `skiprow` takes a list-like input. So your `skip_row_number` should be `skip_row_number = [5]` . The 5 should be an integer not a string.

Comment: Thanks @SSC.  Just tried skip_row_number = [5] but sadly still doesn't work :/

Comment: The question is not clear. You're asking about `skiprows`, but the error you shared comes with the use of `.dropna`. Which is it? If you're looking for a way to match file names to their corresponding rows to skip, you should use a python dictionary. The keys are the file names and the values are lists with row numbers you wish to skip. Figure that out first before you tackle `.dropna`.

Comment: because the skiprow number is not correct, the header won't be correct and  missing.  Therefore, .dropna will return errors because the skiprow is not correct.  The first example "df2 = pd.read_excel(fname, skiprows=5, header=0).dropna(subset=['TreeNodeCode'],how='any')", dropna works perfectly because the header is correct .

Comment: So then the question is: do you know the row numbers/indexes you wish to skip? If so, just provide that list of indexes to the `skiprows` parameter. But if you're looking to skip the first rows after the header row, then you may want to try: `pd.read_excel(fname, header=0, skiprows=range(1,5))`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers! The answers in the comment don't seem to work, but I use a kinda ugly way which it works:

```
               if CLIENT_ID in ('6'):

                df2 = pd.read_excel(fname, skiprows=5, header=0).dropna(subset=['TreeNodeCode'],how='any')

              elif CLIENT_ID in ('7','23'):

                df2 = pd.read_excel(fname, skiprows=4, header=0).dropna(subset=['TreeNodeCode'],how='any')
```